# Rails 4, @font-face, sass, assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline, font-face

I know that there are already questions regarding @font-face, sass and rails 4 but I want to see if anyone has been able to get this working.

My Sass File looks like this:

```
@font-face{ font-family:"FrutigerNextW01-Regular";
src:    url(font-path("4cef6d85-d22a-4541-b469-da13751862aa.eot?#iefix"));
src:    url(font-path("4cef6d85-d22a-4541-b469-da13751862aa.eot?#iefix")) format("eot"),
        url(font-path("d74de079-587d-4049-9cca-50ba02a536f9.woff")) format("woff"),
        url(font-path("07749504-e72d-4fc9-a58d-5b853dd51fc7.ttf")) format("truetype"),
        url(font-path("8178e4eb-8ce0-4c15-a701-4a102b204c0e.svg#8178e4eb-8ce0-4c15-a701-4a102b204c0e")) format("svg");
}
```

I've tried using erb tags, asset-path and every other configuration I can find.

I've tried both of these lines in my application.rb file

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
```

and

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

Am I doing something wrong? I know that some have been able to get this configuration to work, but it's not working for me!

Comment: Thanks for asking. I'm looking for the same thing.

Comment: Does the same thing work with a Rails 3.x app, and not with 4.x ?

Answer (score 3):

I've got a Rails 3.2 app with web fonts that work correctly.

They are stored in `app/assets/fonts` and referenced from my ERB views with the `asset_path()` method (and not `font_path()`).

Here is the copy of my inline style tag :

```html
<style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'QuicksandBook';
    src: url('<%= asset_path('Quicksand_Book-webfont.eot') %>');
    src: local('☺'), url('<%= asset_path('Quicksand_Book-webfont.woff') %>') format('woff'), url('<%= asset_path('Quicksand_Book-webfont.ttf') %>') format('truetype'), url('<%= asset_path('Quicksand_Book-webfont.svg') %>') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'QuicksandBold';
    src: url('<%= asset_path('Quicksand_Bold-webfont.eot') %>');
    src: local('☺'), url('<%= asset_path('Quicksand_Bold-webfont.woff') %>') format('woff'), url('<%= asset_path('Quicksand_Bold-webfont.ttf') %>') format('truetype'), url('<%= asset_path('Quicksand_Bold-webfont.svg') %>') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
  }
</style>
```